# Select max and min Datetime in a range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get Max and Min date from a range in Excel. I used MIN(A9:A18) and Max(A9:A18) and changed the format to date in the result cells, but it's display nothing. 
Date:

[image: Date]

Fields:

[image: Fields]

Format:

[image: Format]

Thanks a lot !

Comment: The "Dates" appear to be text that look like dates and not true dates.  If you change the format of the dates to General, do they change to a number?

Comment: yes it displays 0

Comment: I did tried that way no luck @Tom

Comment: @Tom - did you mean `=DATEVALUE(A9)` ?

Comment: @CLR yup you're absolutely right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dates do indeed appear to be text strings that look like dates, instead of Dates.

You can use the other answer options to correct the cells, so they contain Dates, not Text - or, if this is something that will repeatedly happen, you can perform a `Max` or `Min` on the text using an array formula.

The formula for the `Min` would be:

`=MIN(DATEVALUE(A9:A18))`

**But when keying the formula, do not just hit Enter. To tell Excel you're inputting an array formula, hold down *CTRL+SHIFT* when you hit Enter.**

Then, use exactly the same method for `Max`:

`=MAX(DATEVALUE(A9:A18))`    *[CTRL]+[SHIFT]+[ENTER]*

Comment: Thanks @CLR. This is really simple.

Comment: Whilst this might be simple it's actually slow and very inefficient if you have a large dataset. Fix your data source instead of fudging it

Comment: Agreed. It entirely depends on if the OP is for instance, importing the text, perhaps using automation outside of their control. The time lost in running the Array is much quicker than regularly correcting the cells. However, if it's a one-off, then of course the best option is to correct the cells and not use arrays. Just giving the options.

Answer (score 0):

Insert a column next to your date range and use the following formula:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(A9,4),LEFT(A9,2),MID(A9,4,2))
```

and drag down. Then copy these cells and paste special over your source cells in column `A` with the values of these cells. Then delete the inserted column

Comment: Is that me @TOM

Answer (score 0):

Are you try to change the type of format ? You can customize the type like this `mm/dd/yyyy` in the customize section.

Comment: On an English machine it would be `mm/dd/yyyy`

Comment: Thanks @Tom for your precisions